# Setting matrix values comparing to vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, subset

I want to set NA's in every element of a matrix where the value in a column is greater than or equal to the value of a given vector. For example, I can create a matrix:

```
set.seed(1)
zz <- matrix(data = round(10L * runif(12)), nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
```

which gives for zz:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8    5    7
[2,]    6    5    1
[3,]    5   10    3
[4,]    9    1    9
```

and for the comparison vector (for example):

```
xx <- round(10L * runif(4))
```

where xx is:

```
[1] 6 3 8 2
```

if I perform this operation:

```
apply(zz,2,function(x) x >= xx)
```

I get:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

What I want is everywhere I have a TRUE element I want an NA and everywhere I have a FALSE I get the number in the zz matrix (e.g., manually ...):

```
NA  5  NA
NA  NA 1
5   NA 3
NA  1  NA
```

I can cobble together some "for" loops to do what I want, but is there a vector-based way to do this??

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Comparing a matrix to a vector is done column-wise, so you could just use `zz >= xx`. And `is.na(zz) = zz >= xx`

Comment: Thanks, Alexis. Don't quite understand why "=" is used instead of "<-" but it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
zz[zz>=xx] <- NA

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    5   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA    1
#[3,]    5   NA    3
#[4,]   NA    1   NA
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried this first and it didn't work. Obviously!
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option to get the expected output. We get a logical matrix (`zz >= xx)`, using `NA^` on that returns NA for the TRUE values and 1 for the FALSE, then multiply it with original matrix 'zz' so that NA remains as such while the 1 changes to the corresponding value in 'zz'.

```
NA^(zz >= xx)*zz
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    5   NA
#[2,]   NA   NA    1
#[3,]    5   NA    3
#[4,]   NA    1   NA
```

---

Or another option is `ifelse`

```
ifelse(zz >= xx, NA, zz)
```

#### data

```
zz <- structure(c(8, 6, 5, 9, 5, 5, 10, 1, 7, 1, 3, 9), .Dim = c(4L, 3L))
xx <- c(6, 3, 8, 2)
```

Comment: akrun, the first answer is the trickiest, but it works, as does the second answer, which is easier to follow. Thanks! Ernie